# Android- Saving a photo I have taking into my Gallery

Tags: java, android, camera, android-camera-intent

I'm only a beginner in android development. I have a program that opens the camera when I click on a button to take a photo. That works fine already. However I want to be able to save the image internaly to a certain folder once it is taken. The path I need it saving to is "/storage/emulated/0/DCIM/Camera/image.jpg" Here's what I have so far

```
static final int REQUEST_IMAGE_CAPTURE = 1;
public void onClickbtnCamera(View v){

   Intent takePictureIntent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
        if (takePictureIntent.resolveActivity(getPackageManager()) != null) {
            startActivityForResult(takePictureIntent, REQUEST_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
        }
    }
```

Comment: You need to check 2 things,
1. Check on Manifest file that the following permission is added.
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" /> 2. Check the sdcard path that you have used is exists..